# Winforms: Screen Location of Caret Position

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, caret

How can I find the screen position of the caret for a standard Winforms TextBox?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it only with native interop: [GetCaretPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648402(VS.85).aspx)

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool GetCaretPos(out Point lpPoint);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have been using the TextBox.GetPositionFromCharIndex function. It gives coordinates relative to the top left of the the TextBox.

Comment: The function seems to [not work sometimes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1831219/2388257)