# Winforms RichTextBox: How can I scroll the caret to the middle of the RichTextBox?

Tags: .net, winforms, richtextbox

I want to scroll a RichTextBox so that the caret is approximately in the middle of the RichTextBox.

Something like [RichTextBox.ScrollToCaret()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.scrolltocaret.aspx), except I don't want to put the caret at the very top.

I saw [Winforms: Screen Location of Caret Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027910/winforms-screen-location-of-caret-position), and of course also saw the Win32 function [SetCaretPos()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648405(VS.85).aspx).  But I'm not sure how to translate the x,y required by SetCaretPos into lines in the richtextbox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the rich text box is in _rtb, then you can get the number of visible lines:

```
public int NumberOfVisibleLines
{
    get
    {
        int topIndex = _rtb.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new System.Drawing.Point(1, 1));
        int bottomIndex = _rtb.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new System.Drawing.Point(1, _rtb.Height - 1)); 
        int topLine = _rtb.GetLineFromCharIndex(topIndex);
        int bottomLine = _rtb.GetLineFromCharIndex(bottomIndex);
        int n = bottomLine - topLine + 1;
        return n;
    }
}
```

Then, if you want to scroll the caret to, say, 1/3 of the way from the top of the richtextbox, do this:

```
int startLine = _rtb.GetLineFromCharIndex(ix);
int numVisibleLines = NumberOfVisibleLines;

// only scroll if the line to scroll-to, is larger than the 
// the number of lines that can be displayed at once.
if (startLine > numVisibleLines)
{
    int cix = _rtb.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(startLine - numVisibleLines/3 +1);
    _rtb.Select(cix, cix+1);
    _rtb.ScrollToCaret();
}
```