# Winforms RichTextBox: How can I determine how many lines of text are visible?

Tags: winforms, richtextbox, scroll

I have a Winforms app containing a RichTextBox.

How can I determine how many lines of text are displayed, currently visible?

Reason:  I want to scroll the caret to the middle of the RichTextBox. I can use [RichTextBox.ScrollToCaret()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.scrolltocaret.aspx), but that puts the caret at  the top of the RichTextBox.  I figure, If I know how many lines are displayed, I could move the caret "back" n/2 lines, then call ScrollToCaret(), then restore the original caret position.

**EDIT:**

I found [EM_GETLINECOUNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761586(VS.85).aspx), which I thought was the answer, except the doc says: *The EM_GETLINECOUNT message retrieves the total number of text lines, not just the number of lines that are currently visible.*

Tantalizingly, there is also [EM_GETFIRSTVISIBLELINE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761574(VS.85).aspx), which gets the first visible line, but I couldn't find a GETLASTVISIBLELINE.  ??

---

Related:
[How can I scroll the caret to the middle of the RichTextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773400/winforms-richtextbox-how-can-i-scroll-the-caret-to-the-middle-of-the-richtextbo)

Comment: Just interested - what are you going to do with this information?  You do realise that this could be variable, because you can have different fonts and padding throughout the text.

Comment: It went into building a custom RTB that displays line numbers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567263/how-to-show-number-of-a-line-in-a-richtextbox-c/2668264#2668264

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, this isn't pretty, but it works for me.  Basically I'm checking a point just inside the upper-left corner of the richtextbox and a point just inside the lower left corner of the textbox.  You may have to adjust the point coordinates depending on how your richtextbox is displayed.  Then I get the character index that is closest to each of those two points, and retrieve the line that it is on.

```
Dim topIndex As Integer = RichTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(New Point(1, 1))
Dim bottomIndex As Integer = RichTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(New Point(1, RichTextBox1.Height - 1))

Dim topLine As Integer = RichTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(topIndex)
Dim bottomLine As Integer = RichTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(bottomIndex)

Dim numLinesDisplayed As Integer = bottomLine - topLine
```

I tested it for richtextboxes with multiple sizes of fonts displayed, and it seems to work.  I suspect that the answer that is returned will be off (too small) by one line if the last line of displayed text has a lot of white space under it and the next line is almost ready to be displayed.  If you have a very tall richtextbox, with many lines, this shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

To display the number of lines that a RichTextBox is capable of displaying, even if there is no text there currently, try:

```
Dim s As SizeF = TextRenderer.MeasureText("A", rtb.Font, rtb.Size, TextFormatFlags.WordBreak)
Dim letterHeight As Integer = CInt(s.Height)
Dim displayableLines As Integer = rtb.Height / letterHeight
```

This uses the height of a test letter 'A' in the current font to find the line height in pixels.