# Textbox SelectionStart, SelectionEnd and Caret (Cursor) Position

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, cursor-position

This could be very simple.

I have a textbox on a WinForm, Text = "ABCDEFGH". I need to select "BCD" and leave the I-Beam (cursor, caret, blinking '|') right between the 'A' and the 'B'. Setting SelectionStart = 1 and SelectionLenght = 3 doesn't work and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `SelectionLength` to 0 as [noted in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart.aspx).

> You can programmatically move the caret within the text box by setting
>   the SelectionStart to the position within the text box where you want
>   the caret to move to and set the SelectionLength property to a value
>   of zero (0).

If the issue is that *BCD* is in fact selected, yet you want the cursor moved back before the *B* I don't believe you will be able to do that via the framework properties since selecting text will move the cursor to the end of the text. You would need to use coordinates and a native interop as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027910/winforms-screen-location-of-caret-position).

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool GetCaretPos(out Point lpPoint);
```

You could then call [SetCaretPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648405%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `TextBox.Multiline` property to True, you can then do this by using a negative selection length.  You need to use the `Select()` overload as `SelectionLength` will not permit negative values.

```
textBox.Select(1 + 3, -3);
```